# Geolocation save to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following problem, for some reason the GeoLocation data is not being saved in a text file.

```
<script>
window.onload=function() {
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}
function showPosition(pos){
   $.POST('saver.php', {
        'lat':pos.coords.latitude,
        'lng':pos.coords.longitude
   }, function(res){
       console.log(res);
   });
}
</script>
```

saver.php:

```
<?php
   print_r($_POST);
   $a = fopen("save.txt", "a");
   fwrite($a,"Location: $_POST[lat],$_POST[lng]\n*******************\n");
   fclose($a);
?>
```

Comment: Please post relevant parts of `saver.php`.

Comment: What do you have in your save.txt after executing the script ?

Comment: That fwrite() should probably have $_POST['lat'] instead of $_POST[lat] - same with lng.

Answer (score 0):

Replace :

```
fwrite($a,"Location: $_POST[lat],$_POST[lng]\n*******************\n");
```

With :

```
fwrite($a,"Location: ".$_POST['lat'].",".$_POST['lng']."\n*******************\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is case sensitive!

As a result, `$.POST` is undefined, while `$.post` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.post` (lowercase) instead of `$.POST`. Your script is working fine. In addition make sure that you've included the `jquery` to your script:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

After that you've need to check for geolocation support of your browser and make sure you've allowed browser to use geolocation.

Comment: I've made ​​the changes but still the same there will be no text file created.